# cursor not returning column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting a NullPointerException with a "prntln needs a message" error even though there is data in the cursor. What might I be missing here?

```
 databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
 db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name, group FROM " +
             "groupWorksheet", null);

 if (c != null ) {

 if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
     Log.v(TAG, "has data");
       do {
            String myName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            Log.v(TAG, myName);

       }while (c.moveToNext());
 }
 }else {

Log.v(TAG, "no data");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Cursor.getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) can return null.

You need to check if the result is null and if so, handle it properly. Just knowing the row exist does not verify that data exist in the row itself.